# Accessing API after deploying

Tags: postman, webassembly

I created a WASM solution with two projects, Client and Server with the Server being an API. It works fine on local machine but when I deploy it I keep getting `ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound`. I tried to access the API in Postman but the return is always an HTML file, my index page. So I figure the problem is either I have the wrong endpoint or it was deployed incorrectly.

For deployment I used VS2022 and WebDeployed the API project to a subfolder I created in the host. The client project was deployed to the root folder. I used the subfolder (i.e. domain.com/subfolder/ as my endpoint. Is this the correct method?  What am I missing here?